# Can't replace multiple values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, replace

I have used this code in order to change my values in the column ' Country'

```
 Energy = pd.read_excel('assets/Energy Indicators.xls',header = 17, skip_footer = 38,usecols = [2,3,4,5],na_values=['...'])
 Energy.columns = ['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']
 Energy['Energy Supply'] *= 1000000
 Energy['Country'] = Energy['Country'].replace({'Republic of Korea':'South Korea','United States of America':'United States'})
```

I have used this code as well:

```
Energy['Country'].replace(to_replace = 'United States of America',value="United States",inplace = True)
```

but its not working as well

the dataset looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using this should work.

```
Energy.replace(to_replace = 'United States of America',value="United States",inplace = True)
```

Comment: Nope its not working.

Comment: after running the above command, nothing happens?

Comment: Nope, if I make 'Country' as index and try to load Energy.loc['United Sates'] then it shows error